# Remove Path/code added with Conda Develop

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

So, I made reference to an library of code using `Conda Develop <path>`.  Now, we are moving that code to a subdir using git submodules.  I want to remove that path entry, to verify that the switch happened.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Read the docs](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html): The reverse operation to

```
conda develop <path>
```

is simply

```
conda develop <path> --uninstall
```

"Removes package if installed in 'development mode'  by  deleting
path  from conda.pth file. Ignore other options - just uninstall and exit."

Comment: Straightforward enough. Thx.